# .htaccess rewrite rule interfering with subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this code to prepend `www.` to my site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine, however, I have a subdomain called `users.mysite.com`

if I browse to

`users.mysite.com/login.php`

my browser will redirect me to

`www.users.mysite.com/users/login.php`

which, of course, doesn't exist. Is there any way to modify this rewrite rule so that my subdomain is handled properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^users\.
```